# Выделение элементов Listview

Tags: android, listview, color, background

Хотел сделать задний фон элементов ListView разного цвета, в зависимости от содержания элемента. Сделал.

```
    public class ColorListSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private ListColors colors;
    Context context;

    public ColorListSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setColors(ListColors colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(view != null) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_mark);
            view.setBackgroundColor(colors.getColor(tv));
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Вот что у меня вышло.

[image: Что сделал я]

Но теперь возникла другая проблема. При выделении элемента (если нажать на него и удерживать), он не выделяется (как было по умолчанию - растекающейся заливкой):

[image: как было по умолчанию]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать такое выделение.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно на ту вьюху, на кою слушатель нажатий повешен добавить

`android:foreground="?selecableItemBackground"`

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, по подробнее? На какую вьюху? Если прописать эту строку в xml файле для ListView, то это не работает.

Comment: @ANUCHEEKIBREEKI, вы не показали разметку элемента списка, засим я не знаю куда вам надо вешать. Вешать надо на ту вьюху в элементе списка, на которую повешен слушатель нажатий. Да, через разметку. Можно, наверное, и программно, но это намного сложнее. Также всё зависит от того как у вас слушатели вешаются.